# How can I rebuild if the width of the screen changes in web?

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, flutter-layout

What I want to achieve is, when the web screen width changes, check if you can add or remove a Widget, and rebuild. The problem I'm having is that when the web screen changes it doesn't rebuild it and some Widgets stays hidden because there is no more screen in there or it should add more Widgets in the line.

The two packages I'm using [responsive_builder](https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_builder) and [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view).

My code:

```dart
List<double> _createSizes() {
  Random random = new Random();
  return List.generate(22, (i) => kDefaultHeightImageFeed + random.nextInt(76));
}

class ImageFeed extends StatelessWidget {
  ImageFeed() : _heights = _createSizes();
  final List<double> _heights;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ResponsiveBuilder(
      builder: (context, sizingInformation) {
        double widthScreen = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        int horizontalValue = 2;
        int tileQuantity = 22;

        if (sizingInformation.deviceScreenType == DeviceScreenType.mobile)
          horizontalValue = (widthScreen - 40.0) ~/ 200;
        else if (sizingInformation.deviceScreenType == DeviceScreenType.tablet)
          horizontalValue = (widthScreen - 40.0) ~/ 200;
        else if (sizingInformation.deviceScreenType == DeviceScreenType.desktop)
          horizontalValue = (widthScreen - kDefaultWebPadding) ~/ 250;

        return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
          primary: false,
          crossAxisCount: horizontalValue,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: tileQuantity,
          staggeredTileBuilder: (index) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => ImageFeedDesign(
            image:
                'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1537953773345-d172ccf13cf1?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80',
            place: index.toString(),
            height: _heights[index],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

ImageFeedDesign code:

```dart
class ImageFeedDesign extends StatelessWidget {
  ImageFeedDesign({this.image, this.place, this.height});
  final String image;
  final String place;
  final String distance = '2.834 km';
  final double height;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => Application.router.navigateTo(context, kPlaceRoute + place,
          transition: TransitionType.none),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            // constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 600),
            height: height,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                image: NetworkImage(image),
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 10,
            left: 15,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  place,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: kWhite,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 2.0),
                Text(
                  distance,
                  style: TextStyle(color: kWhite),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(bottom: 10, right: 15, child: kInstagramLigth),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Problem in video:
https://youtu.be/VNxFuLoY6G4

Comment: I've executed your snippet and it's being rebuilt. Could you explain what you're trying to achieve better or perhaps add a drawing?

Comment: @mightybruno I uploaded my problem in YouTube https://youtu.be/VNxFuLoY6G4. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

```dart
List<double> _createSizes() {
  final random = Random();
  return List.generate(40, (i) => 120.0 + random.nextInt(100));
}

class ImageFeed extends StatelessWidget {
  ImageFeed() : _heights = _createSizes();
  final List<double> _heights;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ResponsiveBuilder(
      builder: (context, sizingInformation) {
        int tileQuantity = _heights.length;
        double widthScreen = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

        late int horizontalValue;
        if (sizingInformation.deviceScreenType == DeviceScreenType.desktop) {
          horizontalValue = (widthScreen - 40.0) ~/ 250;
        } else {
          horizontalValue = (widthScreen - 40.0) ~/ 200;
        }

        return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
          mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
          crossAxisCount: max(1, horizontalValue),
          itemCount: tileQuantity,
          staggeredTileBuilder: (index) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
            height: _heights[index],
            child: Image.network(
              'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1537953773345-d172ccf13cf1?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Edit after running your project from github, I've noticed that `StaggeredGridView` doesn't render it's children properly. After hot restart the problem isn't there.

[image]

Comment: For the mobile and tablet I buy you the solution, but for web not. They are a lot of screen width. The problem is that the web is not resizing well, for example, if the are 5 images and you resize the screen for bigger it doesn't add any other image.

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstood what you're trying to do. I've played around with your snippet a bit more but I couldn't reproduce the clipping you've encountered. Could you share the code responsible for `ImageFeedDesign` as well?

Comment: Sure, I just added the `ImageFeedDesign` code. Hopes this reproduces my error.

Comment: I still couldn't reproduce your issue, so it's either caused by one of the widgets you haven't posted or the bug was fixed in recent versions of dependencies. works flawlessly for me on `flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.0-nullsafety.3` and `responsive_builder: ^0.4.0-nullsafety.1`, flutter beta

Comment: I don't use the prerelease, but after trying with it, the error stills. I also use 'flutter upgrade', but nothing. If you wanna test all the code, here is my repository https://github.com/jonhygg99/7paradises

Comment: I've added a screenshot from local env, it's most likely a bug in `StaggeredGridView`

Comment: Thanks for the help